# NuGet package manager settings

Tags: package-management, visual-studio

I added my local feed to the package sources in the Nuget Package Manager Settings window. There is already an official feed from Nuget. There are two arrows which can be used to change the order of the feeds.

Does the order of feeds make a difference? My guess is that if the same package is there in all the feeds then Nuget will get it from the feed at topmost level. But then it is just a guess. 
Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in Pro NuGet Book.
Specifically it says:

"NuGet checks the list of defined package sources, in
order of appearance. This means a package source higher up the list of
package sources will be consulted prior to a repository lower on that list."